# How to Fix x86_64 Memory Offsets (GAS)?

Tags: c, gdb, x86-64, gnu-assembler, opcode

I am working on a project in C, and I've run into an issue. I am trying to hardcode an x86_64 instruction, but the memory addresses aren't coming out quite right. Really, the problem itself is simple; I am just stuck figuring out its solution.

In GDB, I get the following:

```
(gdb) x /7ib f
...
0x7ffff7ff7005: callq  0x80000040072b`
```

That's fine and all, except for one thing: the address I *want* is, according to GDB, `0x40072b` (on a related note, out of curiosity, why is the memory address so high for `f`?) How can I fix this? For reference, here is the hex of the portion I'm working on (just these six bytes):

```
(gdb) x /6xb 0x7ffff7ff7005
0x7ffff7ff7005: 0x48    0xe8    0x20    0x97    0x40    0x08
```

Thanks for any and all assistance.

**Update:**

It has been requested for me to explain how I am coming up with this offset:

Here's what I am working on: I want to implement a way for me to use [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) in C, which I am trying to do by implementing what I've found in [this article](http://www.hokstad.com/how-to-implement-closures) (the part I'm basing this off of is at the very end... and yes, I am aware that the solution to this will be architecture-specific).

Essentially, it encodes a [thunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) as a packed structure with the necessary opcodes to load an environment and call the desired function's location in memory, which then (to the dismay of Dennis Ritchie's ghost) is cast to a `cfunc`, which is defined as

```
typedef void (* cfunc)();
```

After which, it is called as an ordinary function.

It does this by creating a thunk `struct` and, among one or two other things, calculating the offset for the `callq` GAS operation using the following line:

```
             (Pointer to first byte of the ------+
             instruction following the CALL op)  |
                                                 |
                                                 |
          (Function to be called by CALL op)     |
                      |                          |
                      |                          |
thunk->call_offset = code - (void *)&thunk->add_esp[0];
        |
        +--- A Signed Long in the 32-bit version
             (Because Longs are 8 bits in 64-bit
              GCC, I have changed it to being a
              Signed Int)
```

I know this is feasible, for it actually works when compiling the original code in 32-bit mode. What I am trying to do is modify the code to work in 64-bit mode. I presume that I need to pad the offset with some sort of value in order to make it point to the correct memory address, but I am unsure what that value is. That, or perhaps there is another way of writing a call opcode which I can use that will point to the correct memory address.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid I am of no further help here. No 64-bit computer available to test on atm etc. A couple of thoughts, though I suspect they wont do much is: 1. cast to `(char *)` instead of `(void *)` when doing pointer arithmetics. Include `stdint` and use things like `uint32_t`, `uint8_t` etc. instead of `unsigned int` etc. (Longs 8 bit on 64-bit GCC?). You might have to resort to loading address to rbx *REX.W + B8+ rd io* and do a absolute callq (but do not attempt unless you suspect it to be true - IDK).

Comment: It could also likely be helpful if you supplied with the actual C-code for the packed struct and the values you give it. You could also do a primitive hex dump of the struct (after initiation) by something like `void xx(void *buf, int len) { int i; unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)buf; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) printf("%02x ", p[i]); }` and call it by `xx(thunk, sizeof(struct thunk));` – this should give you the raw machine code for the segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 0x48 0xe8 0x20 0x97 0x40 0x08

Translates to:

```
48 e8 20974008
 |  |    |
 |  |    +------ Offset (As of opcode)
 |  +----------- Opcode (CALL)
 +-------------- REX prefix
```

#### 48: REX prefix

```
  0100 1000
    |  ||||
    |  |||+-- B - Extension to MODRM.rm or SIB.base
    |  ||+--- X - Extension to SIB.index
    |  |+---- R - Extension to MODRM.reg
    |  +----- W - 64-bit operand size, else (usually) 32-bit
    +-------- Fixed bit pattern
```

In other words: 64-bit operand size.

#### e8: Opcode

Looking at [instruction manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) one find :

> CALL e8 cd
>
> Call near, ***relative*, displacement *relative* to next instruction**. 32-bit displacement sign extended to 64-bits in 64-bit mode.

Where:

> **cd** — A 4-byte value following the opcode. This value is used to specify a code offset and possibly a new value for the code segment register.

The **cd** is in this case:

> 20 97 40 08

Ordered from little- to big endian we get:

> 08409720 + 6

We add 6 because the offset is relative to next instruction. As the instruction is six bytes.

> 0x48 0xe8 0x20 0x97 0x40 0x08

In other words:

```
callq fun_08409726
```

---

In GDB from your print out:

```
(gdb) x /7ib f
...
0x7ffff7ff7005: callq  0x80000040072b`
```

You get the offset from address `0x7ffff7ff7005` by:

```
0x7ffff7ff7005 + 0x08409726 = 0x80000040072b
      |              |              |
      |              |              +-------- Result address (same as in GDB).
      |              +----------------------- The offset we calculated above.
      +-------------------------------------- Memory offset of the instruction.
```

There might be something going on in GDB, but that does not look quite right.

The (virtual) address `0x000080000040072b` is above `0x00007fffffffffff`. Reason for the address is due to the instruction offset. Now how this offset is generated. (As you say *“I am trying to hardcode an x86_64 instruction”*) you might know best self.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the next line in the GDB output...Doesn't the offset get calculated based on the *next* line's memory address (in which case the offset makes sense....also, that is the pattern I've been seeing)?

Also, are you saying I should ditch the `0x48`? The offset is a calculated offset from two pointers within the C program...from what I can tell, the offset is *correct*, but I am mucking up the encoding, which is leading to the `800000` prefix on the address.

Comment: (Update: I tried ditching the `0x48` prefix, and it seems to have had literally no effect)

Comment: @Morpfh What doesn't look quite right? Looks correct to me: `CALL` is relative to the address of next instruction, which is at  `0x7ffff7ff7005+ 6 == 0x7ffff7ff700b`, and `0x7ffff7ff700b+0x08409720 == 0x80000040072b`.

Comment: @belph Your question appears to be: "I am calculating offset incorrectly, where is my mistake?" -- except you didn't provide any details about *how* you are calculating the offset. You may want to edit your question.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I have updated the question with the calculation procedure.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: What I meant by *“does not look quite right”* is that the address looks wrong (as a result of instruction) – outside usable space, not that the calc is wrong. IIRC I have read somewhere about GDB addresses being skewed as a result of internal workings – but can't find back to it, I'm likely remembering wrong.

Comment: @belph: Yes, relative to next instruction. That is what I meant by the +6. For the rest you might look at my comment(s) below Q.